# NSArray and fast enumeration, always go in index order?

Tags: objective-c, ios

will a fast enumeration of an array always go in index order?

```
for (NSDictionary *zone in myArray)
{
    //do code
}
```

will that always enumerate from index location 0, 1, 2, ..., n?

i prefer fast enumeration over a standard for loop since it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it will:

> For collections or enumerators that have a well-defined order—such as
>   an NSArray or an NSEnumerator instance derived from an array—the
>   enumeration proceeds in that order, so simply counting iterations
>   gives you the proper index into the collection if you need it.

[docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW4)

Answer (score 4):

For fast enumeration of an array with indexes, use blocks:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSObject *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   ...
   // idx is myArray's index
}];
```

Comment: If melsam added "Yes, order is preserved, but if you want an 'index' variable, here is a better solution", then it would answer the question and the obvious follow-on question.